# How to sorting the gridview when i click the header text on gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have developed an asp.net application that has a Gridview control. I want it to sort when I click on the Gridview header text in asp.net. Entity framework is used to bind the gridview.

```
protected void grdmortgagesaver_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
    }   

}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{

 //  You can cache the DataTable for improving performance
     var databind = from i in mortgageentites.Clients orderby i.LastName select i;
    if (databind.Count() > 0)
    {    
        grdmortgagesaver.DataSource = databind.ToList();
        grdmortgagesaver.DataBind();
        DataTable dt = clients;
        if (dt != null)
        {
            // DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
            grdmortgagesaver.DataSource = dv;
            grdmortgagesaver.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a standard ASP.NET System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView, you can simply "Enable Sorting", in the properties pane by setting "AllowSorting" to true or via the "pop-out" on the top right of the control by checking "Enable Sorting"

Comment: Hi i have post my code what i did for sorting... i am using normal  asp.net

Comment: i dont want a custom sorting just i have try like that to get result.is there another sorting order please help me

Answer (score 1):

add AllowSorting="true" in your gridview control and

```
protected void grd_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SortExpression == hdfSortExp.Value)
        {
            if (hdfUpDown.Value == "1")
                hdfUpDown.Value = "0";
            else
                hdfUpDown.Value = "1";
        }
        else //New Column clicked so the default sort direction will be incorporated
            hdfUpDown.Value = "0";

        hdfSortExp.Value = e.SortExpression; //Update the sort column
        BindGrid(hdfSortExp.Value, this.CBool(hdfUpDown.Value));
    }
```

in your c# code

```
public void BindGrid(string sortBy, bool inAsc)
    {
        grd.DataSource = WManager.GetAdminTags(txtSearch.Text.Trim(), sortBy, inAsc);
        grd.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving a response i want bind my tolist data to a dataset how can i do.please help me.

Comment: create a dataview variable and assign dataset table to this view like this ds.table[0].defaultview; and then you can dataview.sort() function calling for this..

Comment: First i can't under stand how can i assign my list values to data set in using entity frame work in sqlserver i can.But using EF how can i do it please help me..

Answer (score 0):

First in your Page in the GridView Declaration Tag add the property `AllowSorting="true"` and in the Gridview_SortCommand try the Following code as guidence

```
try {
    if (SortType == false) {
        SortView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
        //dviewGeneral.Sort = e.SortExpression & " ASC"
        Session.Item("SortOrder") = SortView.Sort.ToString;
        SortType = true;
    } else {
        SortView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
        Session.Item("SortOrder") = SortView.Sort.ToString;
        //dviewGeneral.Sort = e.SortExpression & " DESC"
        SortType = false;
    }
    CMSgrid.SelectedIndex = -1;
    CMSgrid.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
    SortBind();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    UserMsgBox(ex.ToString());
}
```